# What is the solution for - library being requested by various other libraries, but resolves to newer version

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, version-control, ionic3, npm-install

When I add a new firebase analytics plugin to my Ionic app, I get the following error upon running "ionoc cordova build android":

[image: Ionic build error]

> BUILD FAILED in 17s 11 actionable tasks: 11 executed cmd: Command
>   failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an
>   exception.
>
> - What went wrong: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by
>     various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1.
>     Disable t e plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew
>     :app:dependencies.

After lot of trial and error approaches to fix this issue, I have managed to get rid of the error by editing the plugin.xml from the firebase-analytics plugin folder and changing the Android platform preference version (see below):
[image: Plugin platform preference version]

Everything is working OK. However since the above file is not part of source control, the other developers would obviously get the same error when trying to build the project. I want to know where exactly should I make the change so that the project is error free when adding to source control.

Another solution (the first solution actually does this in background) is to edit the \platform\android\project.properties and change the firebase-core version from 16.0.+ to 15.0.+. However, this solution also has the limitation as above when it comes to source control and other developers working on the project.

I did try to update the verison in config.xml from 16.0.+ to 15.0.+, but this has no impact.

Comment: Could it be that the minimal android version defined in the config.xml also defines which version of firebase will be installed? Meaning that maybe you need to change the minimal android sdk and then once somebody does a build it will pull a different firebase version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cordova plugin should fix your issue

> This Cordova/Phonegap plugin for Android aligns various versions of
>   the Play Services library specified by other plugins to a specific
>   version.

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release

Install it then try to build

Comment: Please can you advise what version parameter I need to pass to the call (what is the basis to decide that?) -> "cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=10.+"

Comment: try 16.+ or 15.+

Comment: With 15.+ it didn't work and gave a similar issue. But with 16.+ it worked! So what is this and how does it work?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think it depends by the combination of the google services required by your installed plugins ( and perhaps by the version of the installed android platform ), actually checking this page https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup all services require 16+.